# Check links with getAllLinks

Tags: ide, selenium

I´m testing application with selenium ide and rc. I need verify the links.

Usually I export file from Selenium ide to junit 4, and run file in eclipse. File is as next

package com.example.tests;

import com.thoughtworks.selenium.*;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class login_csupport extends SeleneseTestCase {
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", "http://daisy-w2003.hi.inet/CustomerSupport");
        selenium.start();
    }

```
@Test
public void testLogin_csupport() throws Exception {
    selenium.open("http://daisy-w2003.hi.inet/CustomerSupport/?ReturnUrl=%2fCustomerSupport%2fAccount");
    assertEquals("Calling Cards Customer Support - Inicio", selenium.getTitle());
    selenium.type("UserName", "admin");
    selenium.type("Password", "admin");
    selenium.click("//div[@id='content']/div/form/div[3]/a/span[2]");
    selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
    assertEquals("Calling Cards Customer Support - Gestión", selenium.getTitle());
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    selenium.stop();
}
```

}
Using getAllLinks I´d like check the links of the page. Please, anyone can to help me??

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`assertAllLinks(pattern)` generated from `getAllLinks()`

```
Returns:
the IDs of all links on the page

Returns the IDs of all links on the page.

If a given link has no ID, it will appear as "" in this array.
```